# Выдаёт лишние символы char

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста почему при такой конструкции:

```
char *clear_scr = new char[w * h]();
for (int i = 0; i < w * h; i++) {
    clear_scr[i] = symbol;
}
std::cout << clear_scr;
delete[] clear_scr;
```

выводятся нужные символы, а затем ¤¤¤¤?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что в цикле вы заменяете последний символ конца строки на свой. Например:

```
char *hello = "He";
hello[0] == 'H';
hello[1] == 'e';
hello[2] == '\0';
```

А вы этот "`hello[2]`" затираете своим символом. И `cout` "бежит" дальше пока не найдет `'\0'`.

---

Рабочий вариант:

```
char *clear_scr = new char[w * h]();
for (int i = 0; i < w * h - 1; i++) {
    clear_scr[i] = symbol;
}
std::cout << clear_scr;
delete[] clear_scr;
```

Comment: Ошибку понял, буду знать